# There is a way to download developer console debug logs filtered?

Tags: developer-console, debug, debug-logs

**Hi Guys!**

There is a way to download developer console debug logs filtered?

I made this filter on developer console and my wish is to download only this and not all debug file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only download the entire file. You can use an offline tool, like `grep`, to print out just the parts of the log you're interested in:

```
grep apex-log-12345.log -e ==
```

You can put this into a file with a redirect:

```
grep apex-log-12345.log -e == > debugs.log
```

Comment: Nice, Thank you!!